# Preparing true/false questions with exam class

Tags: packages, exam

I use the [`exam document class`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) to prepare my question papers. While it may have some limitations compared to the similar others available, it has nicely fulfilled my purpose so far.

Now, I need to prepare a question with true/false questions and the `exam` class do not seem to have this feature.

I understand that I can achieve the same effect if I decide to switch to some other class available, but that will need a major overhauling in my setup which may prove to very expensive considering the time I can afford.

One solution could be to use the [eqexam](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eqexam) style file, and prepare something like the ones shown [here](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/story-eqexam/story-eqexam.pdf) (page 3), but the exam document class and the 
eqexam style file conflict since they define environments with identical names (`parts` along with other ones).

What will be your suggestion to prepare true/false questions in the exam class which should have the facility to print answers when I decide to just like the other questions.

Comment: I think with `shortanswer`, `choices` or `checkboxes` environments can have true or false questions.

Comment: @Ignasi `shortanswer` is a definite alternative though it is not actually a true/false environment per se. Thanks for the idea, that will salvage the current situation. Please see [this docuemnt](http://coin.wne.uw.edu.pl/wincenciak/latex/exam.pdf), section 2.2.3, page 7. Surprisingly this package had an identical name to the one in question.

Comment: Jason Alexander's `exam` class was renamed [`examdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/examdesign) some years ago to avoid the problem with Philip Hirschhorn's one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the following True/False format in the `Exam` class. It may or may not suit your needs. I find this layout especially convenient for grading. Part of the true/false question format is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13106/39194) by Gonzalo Medina.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

%\printanswers

% Create a True False question format
\newcommand*{\TrueFalse}[1]{%
\ifprintanswers
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
        \textbf{TRUE}\hspace*{14pt}False
    }{
        True\hspace*{14pt}\textbf{FALSE}
    }
\else
    {True}\hspace*{20pt}False
\fi
} 
%% The following code is based on an answer by Gonzalo Medina
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13106/39194
\newlength\TFlengthA
\newlength\TFlengthB
\settowidth\TFlengthA{\hspace*{1.16in}}
\newcommand\TFQuestion[2]{%
    \setlength\TFlengthB{\linewidth}
    \addtolength\TFlengthB{-\TFlengthA}
    \parbox[t]{\TFlengthA}{\TrueFalse{#1}}\parbox[t]{\TFlengthB}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\fullwidth{%
Circle True or False.  Read each statement in original Greek before answering. (2 points each)
}
\question\TFQuestion{F}{This sentence is false.}
\question\TFQuestion{T}{This sentence is false.}
\question\TFQuestion{T}{A man says that he is lying. Is what he says true or false?}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\printanswers` uncommented, you get the following output.

[image]

Comment: Can not thank you enough for the answer. I like it specially for the fact that it makes the grading process so much easier.

Comment: How can we do these kind of questions in article class?

Comment: I have an answer for you (with code) but you should ask this as a separate question. In short, I used the `ifthenselse` package to replace the `\ifprintanswers` command in the `exam` class. It was a straightfoward replacement so you may be able to figure it out on your own, using my code from above.

Comment: I like your answer, but one thing is still unclear for me. How to make the questions' numbering consistent with other questions? I mean, if I paste your answer between two questions, I disturb the questions order.

Comment: @dawicz The question number should contiue automatically, regardless of where you use them. The first part of the command `\question\TFQuestion` is the `\question` command from the `exam` class. That is how `exam` knows it is a question and continues numbering. I am not clear what you mean when you say you paste the answer between two questions. Everything above `\begin{document}` should be in the preamble of your document. What is disturbed about the numbering? Does it restart at 1?

Comment: @dawicz I think your problem may be because you started a new questions section, rather than just having one.